# Show more columns in content query Sharepoint 2013

Tags: content-query-web-part

How do I set the number of columns shown by content query which retrieves data form a list?

It only shows the Content column and I'd like it to show the Rating column too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 for adding new Fields you should modify the `ItemStyle.xsl`. This file is available in location

```
http://web/sitecollection/style library/XSL Style Sheets
```

I would suggest you create a copy of the file or add a new style template instead of modifying existing templates.

Sample template

```
  <xsl:template name="MyItemStyle" match="Row[@Style='MyItemStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
      <div class="item">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
       <xsl:value-of select="@Ratings" />
       <xsl:value-of select="@Comments" />
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

After adding this, you should Publish and Approve the file. Then edit the Content Query WebPart and choose "Presentation" -> "Item Style" -> "MyItemStyle"

This will bring you the three fields that is mentioned in the style

[image]

Now you can specify the FieldInternal Name and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

By default CQWP shows only one column. However, if you want to show more than one column, then CQWP needs to be customized. The property which you are looking for is `CommonViewFields`. It is used to specify the additional fields that you want to display in the Web Part. See thsi for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457(v=office.14).aspx